# JAVASCRIPT Not working after download webpage offline

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm new here i want to learn about php and javascript by myself.
I have some question
I try download(save full webpage) some website from internet that have login-form and i want to use this log-in section in my test website for test but the problem is.
1.after i save that webpage and open offline (with internet connection) and test log-in, javascript in log-in section not working but other javascript in website is working nomally.
2.If i want to use this login section in my new website (log in to original site,but use it in my site)
how could i do?
as i said at first i'm new about website creator,and sorry about my bad grammars.
Thanks for your help.

ps. this is code in original login section that not working when save page offline.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function testLogin(){
  var params = jQuery('#form2').serialize();

  jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url:  "**https://www.somewebsite.com**",
     data: params,
     success: function(resp){
        var obj = JSON.parse(resp);

        if(obj.URL!=''){
          window.location = obj.URL;
          return;
        }else{
          alert(obj.ErrMsg);
        }
     }
   });
}

<div class="testLogin">
<h5 class="widget-title"><span>เข้าสู่ระบบ</span></h5>
<div class="login">
<form class="login-form" id="form2" name="form2" method="post" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
<div class="login-Input">
<input class="username" id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="ชื่อผู้ใช้" style="cursor: pointer;" autocomplete="off">
<input class="password" id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="รหัสผ่าน" style="cursor: auto;" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="buttonlogin">
<a class="btnLogin" id="btnLogin" href="javascript:;" onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; testLogin();">
<div class="login-btn">
LOGIN
</div>
```

Comment: What's with the `**` around the url? Did you add those here on SO? Have you checked the console in your browsers development tools for potential error messages?

Comment: You can't POST to https from localhost.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSalazarMori - Why wouldn't you be able to do that? It works perfectly fine as long as there are a proper cross-origin setup.

Comment: i can't even do a basic javascript,why you think i am able to hack webpage lol.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSalazarMori - Your comment is still wrong though. There's nothing that says that you can't post to a https-url from localhost. If you meant it in some specific scenario, you need to add that as well.

Comment: i just want to try make some website but i don't have my own database so i just want to test by login to other website only ,please understand me.

Comment: Why don't you just set up a database instead? There are many many articles about setting up MySQL and how to use it using PHP.

Comment: just want to try sir.i want to know if we can make multiple website and use one database for login. but i don't have any mentor so that's why i try it by myself but i'm not good with this, so i copy the whole webpage and try to change something (picture,icon sure i just only try not for commercial)  cause i want to buy some course to learn about this but i want to try it first :D .

Comment: sorry about my bad language and grammars again sir.I'm not a people from Europe.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSalazarMori I think you're confusing `localhost` i.e. a local webserver served over http i.e. `http://localhost` with opening the html file directly in the browser from the filesystem, using the `file://` protocol. You're correct that cross-origin AJAX requests are not permitted when the page is loaded via the `file://` protocol, and that this is done to prevent malicious code from having too many filesystem privileges. OP should have an error in their browser's Console mentioning it, if that's what is happening.

Comment: @sattha14902 "i want to know if we can make multiple website and use one database for login" yes that's possible, e.g. using an API and/or federated identity provider. But we need to know more what you mean by "not working". Have you opened your browser's Developer Tools and checked the Console for errors? As I mentioned to Carlos in my comment above, if you're opening this page as an "offline" page then, for security reasons, you won't be able to make an AJAX request from it, and there will be an error....

Comment: You may need to install your own local webserver and serve the page from there. Even then, the remote website still may not allow cross-origin ("CORS") requests to it and your request may still fail. If the remote website belongs to you, then of course you can change it to allow CORS requests from your other sites.

Comment: P.S. If you don't want to build your own identity system, you could always try using OAuth services like the ones provided Google or Facebook or Microsoft to identify your users - you must have seen lots of websites which say "login with Google" or similar. You can implement the same on your own site without too much trouble, there are plenty of tutorials. Depending on your needs, it might be better than trying to use some other random website which doesn't really support the situation properly.

Comment: I love that you all have discuss on my topic,because i got knowledge from you .Ok i will create my own database first and take more practice. you two can still talk in here, i will keep it for read after i have more knowledge about this, Thank you.